# How to simulate 'except' for string lists in for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a list of strings (`partList`) which is a fraction part of another list of strings (`completeList`) and i want to process an object (through `processObj()`) within a for loop in a way that the current element of the partList will be retracted from the completeList: when the current iteration is on an element of partList then the processing of the object will involve that element and the rest of elements from completeList i do it like so for now:

```
        for (String el: partList) {
            completeList.remove(el);
            //process the target object using as parameters el and the rest of the complete list except el...
            processObj(el,completeList);
            completeList.add(el);
        }
```

Is it the right way of doing it?
Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: It depends on if you want to move those elements to the end of the list, and on what `processObj()` actually does. Like it gets `el` anyway, so it could probably ignore it when encountering in the list.

Comment: exactly, here the order doesn't matter.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter perhaps it would be more appropriate to use a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>` i.e., `completeSet`, not `completeList`.

Comment: no, because in the method i call within the for loop (processObj()) i need the param completeList to be a list

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the purpose of removing then adding back to the same list, but you can use a `Predicate` to accept and process certain values.

```
Predicate<String> accept = (s) -> {
  return true;  // accepts all strings; you could use partList.contains(s) here, or !s.equals(el)
}
completeList.stream()
    .filter(accept.negate()) // Inverse the predicate to implement "except" 
    .forEach(processObj);
```

Replace `forEach` with `map` if you want to modify the stream values, then you can `collect()` to get data back to a list.

Comment: the purpose is set by the `processObj()`. For your reply i was looking more into a standard Java solution (vs a Java-8 one)

Comment: Many people would argue Java 8 is "standard Java". Especially when we are almost 10 releases past that.